# How to use Vala objects/methods from C?

Tags: c, vala

My application is entirely written in C at this point but I'd like to start adding objects in Vala for use in the various C files. I'm aware that I can generate the .c/.h files using valac and include those, but it would be preferable to include them into my automake setup as a source file.

This is trivial to go the other way, just write a vapi file for any of the .c/.h files and add that as a --pkg. Unfortunately it seems to be not as trivial for the way that I want to use.

The relevant additions that I've made nonetheless.

configure.ac:

```
AM_PROG_VALAC([0.12.0])

dnl Only adding these to test the package include in vala
OFS_PACKAGES="--pkg gee-1.0"
AC_SUBST(OFS_PACKAGES)
```

Makefile.am:

```
VALAFLAGS = \
    @OFS_PACKAGES@

src_ofs_SOURCES = \
    src/main.c \
    src/test.vala
```

src/main.c

```
#include "test.h"

...

FooTest *object = foo_test_new ();
```

src/test.vala:

```
using Gee;

namespace Foo {

    public class Test : Object {

        public Test () {
            stdout.printf ("Test construction\n");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run make I get the error

```
src/main.c:10:18: fatal error: test.h: No such file or directory
```

which is no surprise given that the call to valac didn't happen prior to the one to gcc. So the question is really whether or not there's a way to tell automake/make to have valac run first to generate the required files to include?

**UPD:**

Managed to get it to work using the following changes:

Makefile.am:

```
VALAFLAGS = \
    -H ofs.h -C -c
    @OFS_PACKAGES@

src_ofs_SOURCES = \
    src/test.vala \
    src/main.c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Built-Sources-Example.

The easiest fix is to add `test.h` to BUILT_SOURCES:

```
BUILT_SOURCES += src/test.h
CLEANFILES += $(BUILT_SOURCES)
```

You can get this expanded by putting your vala files in their own variable:

```
src_ofs_VALASOURCES = $(filter %.valam,$(src_ofs_SOURCES))
BUILT_SOURCES += $(src_ofs_VALASOURCES:.vala=.h)
```

The alternative is to add it to `nodist_ofs_SOURCES` and to the dependencies of `src/main.$(OBJEXT)`.

Comment: Thanks for those. I was able to get it working by changing the sources order and the valaflags (will post the changes following this) but I will give your suggestions a try because they look more like the correct solution.

Comment: You'll also need to ask valac to generate a C header (--header test.h), and you'll probably want to add a test.h target which depends on the stamp file.  Note also that it's not one header per source file, so use *_SOURCES to generate BUILT_SOURCES probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: @nemequ I was just about to post a reply saying that I tested the suggestions made by ecatmur and found an issue with exactly what you mention. My solution was also to specify a single header file, with --header, for all of the .vala files to use and didn't do the bit to expand .vala=.h. Thanks.